# python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output why installing instagram-scraper

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram-api

I tried to run `pip install instagram-scraper` and `pip install igramscraper` in windows terminal but I got this error:

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py
> egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

and full text of error is:

```
Using cached instagram-scraper-1.9.0.tar.gz (35 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\a\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-imeolj6n\\instagram-scraper\\setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'C:\\Users\\a\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-imeolj6n\\instagram-scraper\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-pvp8sv0c'
         cwd: C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-imeolj6n\instagram-scraper\
    Complete output (28 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2470, in resolve
        return functools.reduce(getattr, self.attrs, module)
    AttributeError: type object 'Distribution' has no attribute '_finalize_feature_opts'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-imeolj6n\instagram-scraper\setup.py", line 31, in <module>
        keywords=['instagram', 'scraper', 'download', 'media', 'photos', 'videos']
      File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 161, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 426, in init
        k: v for k, v in attrs.items()
      File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 292, in init
        self.finalize_options()
      File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 716, in finalize_options
        for ep in sorted(eps, key=by_order):
      File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 715, in <lambda>
        eps = map(lambda e: e.load(), pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(group))
      File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2462, in load
        return self.resolve()
      File "c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2472, in resolve
        raise ImportError(str(exc))
    ImportError: type object 'Distribution' has no attribute '_finalize_feature_opts'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I'm using python3 and it has been set in environment variables as path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find an exact solution for this. I just used virtual environment for installing modules for this special project to remove such conflicts.

Comment: Looking for a solution to this too.